Error: "Invalid use of incomplete typeof 'DH' {aka 'struct dh_st'}" when using OpenSSL DH function in C
I'm Trying to implement a server-client application in C that uses OpenSSL's Diffie-Hellman key exchange for secure communication.However, during compliation, I'm encountering the following error: invalid use of incomplete typeof 'DH' {aka 'struct dh_st'}. I've ensured that I'm including the necessary OpenSSL header files("#include <openssl/dh.h>") and linking against the OpenSSL library('-lssl -lcrypto'). However, I'm still encountering this error. Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?.
Additionally,any insights or suggestions on improving the code or implementing Diffie-Hellman key exchange securely would be greatly appreciated.
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define PRIME_LEN 128
#define GENERATOR 2

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);
    DH *dh = NULL;

    // Create socket
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket < 0) {
        error("Error opening socket");
    }

    // Initialize server address structure
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket to the specified port
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
        error("Binding failed");
    }

    // Listen for incoming connections
    listen(server_socket, 5);
    printf("Server listening on port %d...\n", PORT);

    // Accept connection from client
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_length);
    if (client_socket < 0) {
        error("Error accepting connection");
    }

    printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), ntohs(client_address.sin_port));

    // Initialize Diffie-Hellman parameters
    if ((dh = DH_new()) == NULL) {
        error("Error initializing DH parameters");
    }

    if (DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, PRIME_LEN, GENERATOR, NULL) != 1) {
        error("Error generating DH parameters");
    }

    // Send prime and generator to client
    BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    char *prime_str = BN_bn2hex(dh->p);
    char *generator_str = BN_bn2hex(dh->g);

    send(client_socket, prime_str, strlen(prime_str) + 1, 0);
    send(client_socket, generator_str, strlen(generator_str) + 1, 0);

    // Receive client's public key
    char client_public_key_str[PRIME_LEN];
    recv(client_socket, client_public_key_str, PRIME_LEN, 0);
    BIGNUM *client_public_key = BN_new();
    BN_hex2bn(&client_public_key, client_public_key_str);

    // Generate shared secret
    char *shared_secret_str = BN_bn2hex(DH_compute_key(dh, client_public_key, NULL));
    printf("Shared secret: %s\n", shared_secret_str);

    // Clean up
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    DH_free(dh);
    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}


What version of OpenSSL?

OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

Missing definitions in Headerfile dh.h (openssl 1.1.0f) may help. Looks like there are functions you should use to retrieve members of that struct.

Changes are 7+ years old: "All structures in libssl public header files have been removed so that they are "opaque" to library users. You should use the provided accessor functions instead"
